# android using Service to update seekbar

Tags: android

I am trying to run MP3 Playback service in the background which implements aidl interface. Here is my aidl interface:

```
interface MPInterface {

              void clearPlaylist();

              void addSongPlaylist( in String song );

              void playFile( in int position );       

              void pause();

              void stop();

              void skipForward();

              void skipBack();

              void test(in String track);

              int getCurrentDuration();

              int getDuration();

      }
```

Afterwards I create MediaPlayerService which implements above MPInterface and then bind the service to activity. Normal methods like playFile(), stop() or pause() work flawlessly. But they are all background task. I want my service and interface able to interact with UI element like seekbar (such as when you touch the seekbar mediaplayer seek to the point or seekbar progress updates accordingly to mediaplayer progress). Any good pointer or tutorial to help me achieve this?

Comment: the point i struggle here is MediaPlayer instance only existed locally in Service and only able to interact through interface. Hence I can't call forth the object at activity and set event listener like onBufferingUpdate in order for it to update the seekbar in activity accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a BroadcastIntent? It should let you send data from your UI element and the BroadcastReceiver could connect to your service and then push the data across it. Just an idea.